# Can't use ADODB.Connect for delete queries in SQLite Database

Tags: vba, sqlite, ms-access, adodb

I need to delete a row in my SQLite database but ADODB Connections 'Execute' doesn't seem to work. I think that maybe it's because of my query or is my syntax just wrong

```
Dim cn As Object
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim szlsql AS String


cn.Open "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=C:\mydatabase.db;"
szlsql = "DELETE Table.var " _
                 & " From Table" _
                 & " Where (((TAble.var) = " & "'" & sString & "'" & "))"

cn.Execute (szlsql)
```

The expected result would be that the query works and the row gets deleted but just throws an error message. This is assuming that sString is a string

Comment: Sorry! Modified it to Dim and it still throws an error when executing cn.Execute

Comment: "just throws an error message" is not a very useful description of what's actually happening - always best to include the text of the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
szlsql = "DELETE From Table Where TAble.var = " & "'" & sString & "'"

cn.Execute szlsql   '<< no need for parentheses here
```